# Can I make Windows 8 Applcations with AS3

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, windows-8, flashdevelop

Hey guys just had a quick question. Is it possible to make Windows 8 or 8.1 Applications using Flash CS6 and Flash Develop as a external coding program basically Action Script 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash apps run on the flash player, so if an operating system supports the flash player, the application will run fine.

AIR allows you to create desktop applications that have expanded capabilities such as local file management. AIR is cross platform, so you can develop for Windows, OSX, iOS, and Android.

However, you are somewhat limited to what the AIR framework exposes to you, so you likely won't be able to utilize some aspects of the OS that you could in making a C++ Windows application.

So, yes it's doable, however what you would specifically like to do, might or might not be something that AIR or Flash provides.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean native windows 8 applications (using the UI/live tiles), like you would publish for Android or iOS with Flash CS6 or CC, no.